# visual studio signing error: this certificate is not trusted on this PC

Tags: windows, visual-studio, certificate, publish

I am trying to sign a UWP app, either debug or release, for the purpose of testing on some other devices. My certificate appears not to be valid.

Here are my steps:

- I right click on my UWP project, choose "publish", then "create app packages".
- In the popup, I choose "sideloading".
- Then I get a step asking whether I'd like to sign the package.
- I want to choose "yes". I have a certificate where the `subject` matches the `publisher` in my manifest. But, just below, it shows a message "this certificate is not trusted on this PC".

If I continue, VS will create a folder containing some installation files. If I click on "...x64.msixbundle", it shows a dialog that says "update ...?", with a note "untrusted app" and a message below "this app package is not signed with a trusted certificate..." (Alternatively, I can run the Install.ps1 script in the powershell, having the same results.) I cannot go further. And, this is on  same PC that I'm doing my development.

I've attempted to follow the instructions on [Create a certificate for package signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing), and some of the adjacent pages. They infer that using the VS wizard should simply work.

P.S. I have never signed a Windows app before. Maybe I should be doing it in a completely different manner ?

Comment: "this certificate is not trusted on this PC" - you may need to add this certificate to the trusted in your pc for visual studio sign process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate where the subject matches the publisher needs to be trusted.

So what to do:

a) The certificate is self signed (The issuer is the same as the subject)

- Run `certlm.msc` (for machine wide trust) or `certmgr.msc` for current user trust.
- Import the certificate to the `Trusted Root Certificate Authorities`

b) The certificate is NOT self signed (The issuer is NOT the same as the subject)

You should not need to do anything if you bought a real code signing certificate as you pay for exactly the trust we are establishing...

- Get the root/issuer certificate

  - **have a *.cer**?

    - double click the cer file
    - click the `Certificate Path` tab.
    - double click the first certificate in the tree - if there is only one ask where you got the certificate from!
    - On the newly opened window click the `Details` tab
    - Click the `Copy to file` button to save the root certificate.
  - have a *.pfx import it

    - Run `certmgr.msc`
    - Right click on `Personal` and select `Advanced Tasks | Import` to import the pfx file.
    - Identify the imported certificate(s) and export the root certificate (see have a *.cer)
- Run `certlm.msc` (for machine wide trust) or `certmgr.msc` for current user trust.
- Import the root certificate to the `Trusted Root Certificate Authorities`

For package signing there are additional requirements on the certificate:

> The certificate that you use to sign the app package must meet these criteria:
>
> - The subject name of the certificate must match the Publisher attribute that is contained in the Identity element of the AppxManifest.xml file that is stored within the package. The publisher name is part of the identity of a packaged Windows app, so you have to make the subject name of the certificate match the publisher name of the app. This allows the identity of signed packages to be checked against the digital signature. For info about signing errors that can arise from signing an app package using SignTool, see the Remarks section of [How to create an app package signing certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-create-a-package-signing-certificate).
> - The certificate must be valid for code signing. This means that both of these items must be true:
>
>   - The Extended Key Usage (EKU) field of the certificate must either be unset or contain the EKU value for code signing (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3).
>   - The Key Usage (KU) field of the certificate must either be unset or contain the usage bit for digital signature (0x80).
> - The certificate contains a private key.
> - The certificate is valid. It is active, hasn't expired, and hasn't been revoked.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-sign-a-package-using-signtool

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I'm still stuck. I have a self signed cert. I followed your steps: first installed it, then in certlm.msc. I found it and moved it to "trusted root...". Then I tried reinstalling the app. Got the same error "This app package is not signed with a trusted certificate...". Maybe there's another step I need to take to produce the certificate ? I'm really puzzled why this is so hard.

Comment: To be clear, "issued by" and "issued to" are the same (my name). And the certificate was placed in the same folder as the msix file, by the VS publish action.

Comment: any possibility to get you to have another look at this. It must be something simple that I'm skipping. Surely millions of developers do this all the time !

Comment: Can you check if your certificate matches the listed criteria: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-sign-a-package-using-signtool

Comment: Hello. I'm looking at the criteria on the page you reference. I know from VS when I selected the certificate that publisher == subject. If I run ceretlm, it shows that from == to, and I assume that's the same thing. It also shows "intended purposes" is "code signing" but the number series is different. I don't know how to check the other criteria. The only tools I've installed are those which come with VS. For example, I don't have signtool and don't see a way to install it independently. If possible, can you explain how I check the rest of the criteria ? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: One more note: in certlm, if I click "properties" for the cert, I see on the "general: tab that it's marked "enable all purposes". The "enable only..." is unchecked and in the greyed out box it shows "code singning" and the number string (not sure what that represents).

Comment: SignTool, which is part of the Windows SDK. The SDK can be installed with Visual Studio or downloaded separately: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/. The publisher equals the subject (including `CN=` and casing and whitespaces). In certlm the certificate has a small key symbol overlayed (private key present), click "properties" and see the details tab for `Enhanced Key Usage`: this must list `Code Signing (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)
`, `Key Usage` must be `Digital Signature (80)`. The certificate is valid. It is active, hasn't expired, and hasn't been revoked.

Comment: I removed the installed certificate and went through the publish process again, with a different certificate. That one is marked "code signing" and the installation worked. I'm not sure exactly what I did to avoid using the bad certificate, or if it even exists anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Configure VS to use the customer CA (Certificate Authority) that signed the certificate you want to use.

This CA should be the root CA and thus any intermediate CA will be trusted as well.

The general cause of this problem is when the root CA is missing and the trust chain can not be completed, meaning you may have only the intermediate CA installed.

Comment: He said that  "issued by" and "issued to" are the same - so it seems to be self signed.